# How MarkerCluster work with MarkerWithlabel

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have markerwith label works fine,but now I want to use markerCluster for tidy purpose.
I find a [tut for markerCluster](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html) ,but the code doesn't work for me.

I just try implement easiest example,which seems only need add 1 line:

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

And I have added the js script also.

But doesn't work,the markers are displayed but not clustered.

I think its maybe I create markerwithlabel contains label content (which is different form normal marker format)
following is my js code in html,this html view is in ruby on rails view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%= include_gon %>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <style type="text/css">
   .labelsn {
     color: green;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: left;
     width: 40px;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }

   .labelsv {
     color: blue;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 30px;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/markerclusterer.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var iw=[];
   var alladdress=[];
   var allmarkers=[];
   function initMap() {

     var clatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.352083, 103.819836);
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 12,
         center: clatlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
     for(i=0;i<gon.astatic.length;i++){


       alladdress.push(new google.maps.LatLng(gon.astatic[i][1], gon.astatic[i][2]));
       if(i<gon.vnum){
       allmarkers[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({position: alladdress[i],icon:"/assets/green_MarkerV.png" ,title: gon.astatic[i][0],labelClass: "labelsv",labelContent: gon.astatic[i][3]});}
       else
       {
      allmarkers[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({position: alladdress[i],icon:"/assets/green_MarkerN.png" ,title: gon.astatic[i][0],labelClass: "labelsn",labelContent: gon.astatic[i][3]});
       }


       var mc=new MarkerClusterer(map,allmarkers); \\what I have added for cluster 
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle',function(){

mc.getTotalClusters();

})          
     }

   google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(window,'load',initialize);
   }


    var ajax_call = function() {

     $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"gmaps/test",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(result){
        for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
       {
       allmarkers[i].labelContent=result[i];
       allmarkers[i].label.setContent();
       }

        }})
   };
   var interval = 1000*60*5
   setInterval(ajax_call,interval);
 </script>
</head>

<body onload="initMap()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 945px; height: 700px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone deal with this before?thanks in advance.

Comment: Define _"doesn't work"_

Comment: the markers are displayed,but not clustered

Comment: we need to see more of your code, what's in the `mcOptions`, how are you creating the markers, etc

Comment: @duncan I have add the code,this code works for me with markerwithlebels,I add few lines hope it can work with markerCluster...

Comment: The MarkerClusterer expects an array of `google.maps.Marker` objects.  You're giving it an array of whatever the `MarkerWithLabel` constructor creates

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could  get it working is, by using MarkerClustererPlus ( newer version of previous build ). https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus